# Calculating Conversion Rate In MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, syntax-error

I'm trying to calculate the conversion rate of clicks and unique visitors for local analytic part of a website. MySQL 5.1.73, appears to not like my query. I'm not sure if the sources I'm getting are using deprecated syntax, or I'm simply not asking the correct question in Google.

```
SELECT 
    (SUM(click1) DIV SUM(unique) * 100) /* <<<< Synrax Error Here */
FROM
    stats_clicks
WHERE
aid = 10050 AND
timestamp_local BETWEEN '2014/01/01' AND '2015/12/01'
```

Sorry if this is a very beginner-isk question. A lot of my resources are not working in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(100 * SUM(click1) / SUM(`unique`))
```

Comment: ah, that's right. "unique" is a mysql keyword. Jeeze, it's been too long since I've done a good amount of sql... Thanks vkp!

Answer (score 3):

`unique` is a reserved word in SQL. The best idea would probably be to rename it to `unique_clicks` or something down those lines. If that is not possible, you can escape it with forward quotes (`s).

Additionally, while `div` is perfectly legal syntax in MySQL, it performs integer division. Chances are you meant to use floating point division, which can simply be done with the `/` operator:

```
SELECT (SUM(click1) / SUM(`unique`) * 100)
```